# Is there any multi-purpose package in PGF I can use to simplify the following?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I want to avoid using `\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}` and

```
\FPeval\height{round(6*sin(pi/3):6)}%
\begin{pspicture}(6,\height)
```

just for the sake of getting more compact code, i.e., without using a temporary variable `\height`. It is not a big problem to use the above approach actually but I am just curios whether or not I can make it more compact.

What I want to achieve is to check whether or not there is a useful package in PGF to let me rewrite the above code as follows.

```
\begin{pspicture}(6,6*sin(pi/3))
```

I have seen someone use `calc` but I have not tried it yet. The complete code is given as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\begin{document}
% not so compact
\FPeval\height{round(6*sin(pi/3):6)}%
\begin{pspicture}(6,\height)
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}

% preferred
\begin{pspicture}(6,6*sin(pi/3))
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If there is no answer in 7 days, I will delete this question to save more space on the server.

Comment: I don't think, that *only* using `calc` for this is possible, because it only supports `+-*/` and no functions like `sin`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: OK. It means that I need sinful packages.

Comment: If this is acceptable, you can express sine through the first few terms of the [taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition) using only `+-*/`. Nevertheless you will still need a temporary length to store the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Remarks

You can use `l3fp` which supports many builtin functions. It is automatically loaded by `xparse`.

Let's look at the definition and elaborate what it does

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }
```

1. `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` is 'expandable', which allows `\eval` to be used where TeX 'expects' a number: most document commands should be 'protected', which is what `\NewDocumentCommand` does.
2. `{\eval}` is the name of the new macro.
3. `{m}` stands for one **m**andatory argument (`o` for optional, `s` for star).
4. `{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }` is the definiton of `\eval`. It calls `\fp_to_decimal` from `l3fp` with the first argument `#1`. The `n` after the colon stands for the type of value, that is expected by `\fp_to_decimal`; `n` stands for a braced token list.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor

% FP
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% l3fp
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% PGF
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
% FP
\FPeval\height{round(6*sin(pi/3):6)}%
\begin{pspicture}(6,\height)
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}

% l3fp
\begin{pspicture}(6,\eval{6*sin(pi/3)})
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}

% PGF
% don't forget "r" to tell PGF, that the argument is in radians
\pgfmathparse{6*sin(pi/3 r)}
\begin{pspicture}(6,\pgfmathresult)
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but I am waiting for someone who can remove `\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff` if possible.

Comment: @StiffJokes `\edef\eval#1{\expandafter\noexpand\csname\detokenize{fp_to_decimal:n}\endcsname{#1}}` :-)

Comment: Now featuring PGF.

Comment: @henrimenke I'd avoid making this unexpandable, as you may well want to to evaluation in an expansion context

Comment: @JosephWright How can I expand the argument `#1` first? I don't know how to `\expandafter` in `expl3`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Well that's `\exp_after:wN`, but what I meant is that `\NewDocumentCommand` is not such a good choice here as `\fp_eval:n` is expandable, so I'd use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Why isn't `\eval`-like macro available out of the box when loading `xparse`? In other words, why do we need to define it first?

Comment: @StiffJokes `xparse` is about creating document commands, and provides none itself. `expl3` is about programming, and doesn't provide document commands. I'd say we hope people will pick up expressions (int/dim/skip/fp) within their code rather than needing to have a document-level 'do evaluation' command.

Comment: Could you elaborate more detailed for what you did in `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }`? What is `m`, `n` and perhaps also `#1`?

Comment: @StiffJokes See my updated answer. @JosephWright Could you please edit the answer and explain `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`?

Comment: What is the type of value of `n` which is a braced token list?